# setInterval implementation problems

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement a function that changes the value of a variable (paddle speed in a simple pong game) but the timer is running very fast and the paddle speed doesn't seem to be changing correctly.

I've created a function that executes each time the `start game` button is pressed, which I'm using as a timer:

```
function setTimer () {
    setInterval(function () {
       trialWindow += 1;
    }, 1000);
  console.log(trialWindow);
}
```

This timer is executed by pressing the start button

```
startBtn.addEventListener('click', setTimer);
```

I have another function set up to increment `canvas.paddleOneVelocityY` whenever the `trialWindow` variable is a multiple of 15

```
function userSpeed () {
  if (trialWindow % 15 === 0)
  {canvas.paddleOneVelocityY = getRandomNumber(5, 20)};
  console.log(canvas.paddleOneVelocityY);
}
```

these functions are called in the `startGame` function:

```
function startGame() {
  gameInProgress = true;
  gameplay.className = '';
  startMenu.className = '';
  gameOverMenu.className = '';
  pauseMenu.className = '';
  gamePaused = false;
  gameInterval = window.setInterval(function() {
    moveEverything();
    drawEverything();
    setTimer();
    userSpeed();
  }, 1000/fps);
}
```

I've tried moving `setTimer` and `userSpeed` to different positions in the order of functions called in `gameInterval` and the timer seems to stop completely.

any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: It seems like you are calling `userSpeed()` only when the game starts, not every time `trialWindow` is updated.

Comment: You're calling `setTimer` every frame, so `trialWindow` will be incremented much faster than every one second.

Comment: FYI! You don't need to nest single-line if statements. `if (trialWindow % 15 === 0) canvas.paddleOneVelocityY = getRandomNumber(5, 20);` would work just as fine and look cleaner (as long as you put them on seperate lines).

Comment: You have a window.setInterval calling another window.setInterval without any usage of window.clearInterval, which might just explode.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimer` creates a *new* interval timer (a timer that repeats) every time it's called. You're calling it from inside the callback of another interval timer:

```js
gameInterval = window.setInterval(function() { // <== This function repeats
  moveEverything();
  drawEverything();
  setTimer();                                  // <== This creates a repeating
  userSpeed();                                 //     timer every time it's called
}, 1000/fps);
```

Instead, just call `setTimer` once, when you want to start the timer it starts.

---

Regarding your outer timer running at `1000/fps` milliseconds, you might want to look at [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I understand how the function is working much better now

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want:

```js
function setTimer() {
    setInterval(function () {
        trialWindow += 1;
        userSpeed();
        console.log(trialWindow);
    }, 1000);
}

function userSpeed() {
    if (trialWindow % 15 === 0) {
        canvas.paddleOneVelocityY = getRandomNumber(5, 20)
    };
    console.log(canvas.paddleOneVelocityY);
}

function startGame() {
    gameInProgress = true;
    gameplay.className = '';
    startMenu.className = '';
    gameOverMenu.className = '';
    pauseMenu.className = '';
    gamePaused = false;
    setTimer();
    gameInterval = window.setInterval(function () {
        moveEverything();
        drawEverything();
    }, 1000 / fps);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="startGame()">Start</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly! I really appreciate your help